Variance after factor analysis in Stata
I run a factor analysis in Stata (-factor- command) and get the eigenvalues for each factor. Then, I do a rotation, and the table presents not the eigenvalues, but the variance. I have two questions:

Should I use the eigenvalues (before rotation) or the variance (after rotation) in deciding which factors to keep?
If I should use the variance, does the same cutoff role of eigenvalues>1 apply to the variance (i.e., I should use only factors with variance>1).

Thanks!

This might also appear relevant https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/154415/3277

"in Stata" is irrelevant to your question. The record shows that I am very positive about Stata.
